# Dynamically adding <li/> to <ul/> in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to add list items to unordered lists in jquery mobile, but the formatting doesn't seem to be created properly.

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="b">
                    <li data-role="list-divider">
                        Title Divider
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="test.html" data-transition="slide">List item 1</a>
                    </li>

 </ul>
```

Script:

```
$('ul').append('<li><a>hello</a></li>');
```

For some reason the li generated dynamically doesn't display the same way as the one that's statically created. Does anyone know why and how I can make it the same?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('ul').append($('<li/>', {    //here appending `<li>`
    'data-role': "list-divider"
}).append($('<a/>', {    //here appending `<a>` into `<li>`
    'href': 'test.html',
    'data-transition': 'slide',
    'text': 'hello'
})));

$('ul').listview('refresh');
```

Comment: @cfarm54 Please check this out, I think it may work.If not please comment me.

Comment: no doesn't work. i dont think you can just append it in the jquery-mobile framework. have you tried using the libraries? jquerymobile.com

Comment: @cfarm54 after appending `<li>` you need to call `$('ul').listview('refresh')` for refreshing. Try this, if not please comment me.

Comment: This code is slow, complicated AND the answer doesn't contain a solution - the comment does.

Comment: @naugtur Hi friend, showing due respect on your comment i want to comment you that i give the solution first and it woked for cfarm54 though it finalize by comment. so why you down vote me?

Comment: Just to force you to update the answer. Downvote cancelled. :) All other is valid - the way you create elements is unreadable for beginners and slower than pushing a html string. Your way of adding elements is useful when more advanced methods are applied to elements - like event binding

Comment: @naugtur thanks for you contructive comment.As a new user it may be fault by me and this type of advises and comments are valuable for me. Thanks again.

Comment: @abdullah.abcoder I'm glad you look at it that way. +1 for attitude! Good luck.

Comment: This is the right answer no matter what, i've stuggleling with this issue forever and ever....

Answer (score 45):

The answers provided turned out to be a little bit messy...

`$('ul').append('<li><a>hello</a></li>');` is ok, but it needs to refresh the listview, so all you need is:

```
$('ul').append('<li><a>hello</a></li>').listview('refresh');
```

Comment: How did I answer my own question if OP is @cfarm54 and I am @naugtur?

Comment: @EJP - even if he did answer his own question, that is an encouraged practice on stackexchange and he shouldn't be chastised for it.

Comment: I was unaware that answering your own question was bad.  In fact I think there is a badge for that.

Comment: @AnthonyTopper Yes, Answering your own question when you find an answer yourself is encouraged. It's a way of sharing knowledge. Some people see bad intention in it because you get reputation points for both the question and the answer. Some people look at gaining rep as if it was actual money or something. Anyway, what EJP was suggesting is simply incorrect. You should never post answers to questions as comments just because you asked the question yourself. If you need more info, look through http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions and links there

Answer (score 2):

And if you want to change the attributes of UL, you might have to call .trigger('create') for the enclosing div. this ensures that UL is created again with properties reset.

Comment: This is correct also, but much more general - you can refresh any section of the document with this. And there's lots of questions on SO asking about that :)

Answer (score 0):

Your <a> tag is not referencing a webpage.

try:

```
$('ul').append('<li><a href="test2.html' data-transition="slide" />List Item 2</li>');
```

Comment: +1 omiting the `href` attribute changes the style of the link.

Comment: @Cyber Sleuth Omega: Good try but this is not valid HTML. There is no opening <li> and no closing </a>. @cfarm54 fix those and it should work.

Comment: @naugtur: according to your solution answer, 'it is OK'. Make up your mind

Comment: `.listview('refresh')` is an answer. OP already did append some html. attributes don't change anything

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add a class to the list tag

```
$('<ul>').append( $('<li>').attr('class','ui-li ui-li-static ui-btn-up-c ui-li-last').append('hello'))  ;
```

JQuery mobile automatically adds a class to the list items, which can be seen if you run your page in firefox and debug it using firebug. Select whatever class has been applied and add it to your dynamically generated li tag.

Comment: This is not  a good practice. What happen when a new version is released and add other classes? Your source will be break. The better solution is always use the api of the framework used, in this case, use jquerymobile api.