# how to "refresh" UL after adding new LI with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I think it's similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5925810), but my problem is about jQuery and HTML5. I'm adding a `<LI>` element to `<UL>` and links (`<a href="..">`) added inside apears as plain text, not clickable. Besides that, images are not visible, while `<img src="..">` elements are being added propertly.

Looks like I need some "refresh" trick to do after using `append()`. Which one?

This is my code, just in case:

```
$('ul').append($('<li/>').append($('<img/>').attr('src', 'http://example.com')));
```

The image is not visible, while HTML is being build correctly. I'm trying in Safari 5.1 on Mac.

BTW, everything works perfectly fine in Firefox 10.0. Maybe the actual problem is that I'm using XML+XSL formatting in Safari and plain HTML5 in Firefox..

Comment: Not 100% sure about how append works, but to me it looks like you are appending the image outside of the li (directly under the ul). And does not attr need an attribute name (like src)? Can you check the resulting DOM?

Comment: I just corrected my example. The resulting DOM looks perfectly correct.

Comment: is this jQuery mobile? If so, you do need some kind of refresh.

Comment: No, it's not jQuery mobile, just jquery 1.7.2 in Safari on Mac

Comment: Anything in the error console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how it works instead (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834487) also):

```
$('#list').html('<li>foo</li>');
```

Answer (score 0):

This will add an li element with an image in it.

```
   $("ul").append("<li><img src='http://www.yourimage/normal.JPG' /> </li>");
```

Here is the sample : http://jsfiddle.net/xchXQ/1/

Comment: This example doesn't work in my case, see why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834487