# How to convert jQuery object to XML/HTML?

Tags: jquery

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
$('<abc/>').append('<x/>').html()
```

I expect it to be: `"<abc><x/></abc>"`. Am I wrong?

Comment: please explain further, your question makes 0 sense right now

Comment: I'm trying to build HTML from jquery elements. I just need to build this text: '<abc><x/></abc>' (for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hug your elements in a parent container as such:

```
$('<div>').append($('<abc/>').append('<x/>')).html()
```

You'll get the result you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/tuTAK/2/

Comment: Thanks, you're right. But it doesn't work with XML+XSL. Looks like my problem is somewhere else.

Comment: this is the full problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834487. if you add your code there you will see the problem

Answer (score 0):

You should be adding an id attribute to your abc tag

```
<abc id="AbcId">
```

and referencing it like this:

```
$('#AbcId').append('<x/>')
```

Comment: He is not referencing an already present element. He wants to create a new element $('<abc/>').

Comment: I don't have an HTML page, I'm working with created on-fly jquery elements. You misunderstood the question

Comment: Okay, I see. Apologies for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

.html() returns child elements of the selected object. In your case, it should return this:

```
<x></x>
```

If you want to get out html, you can write a quick function:

```
$.fn.outerHTML = function() {
    return $('<div>').append( this.eq(0).clone() ).html();
};
```

Now if you re-write your code with outerHTML():

```
$('<abc/>').append('<x/>').outerHTML();
```

You will get this:

```
<abc><x><x/></abc>
```

Answer (score 0):

in that case, i guess what you have is close to correct, for instance, build a div with a header in it that says "Title";

`$("<div />").append($("<h1 />").text("Title"))`

or a div with a p element with a link in it after some text

`$("<div />").append($("<p />").text("Mail Me Here:").append($("<a />").attr("href", "mailto:somemail@gmail.com").text("someMail@Gmail.com")))`

append it to the body with

`...eMail@Gmail.com"))).appendTo($("body"))`

Keep in mind you can also .prepend and .prependTo elements

See an example of appending new table rows from data as

[found in this fiddle i made for another answer](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/YU4ha/)

Comment: and then nothing unless you want to append it to something

Answer (score 0):

```
$("<abx>").append("<x/>")[0].outerHTML
```

result :

```
"<abx><x></x></abx>"
```

.html() only outputs the content of

```
$("<abx>")
```