# How to add to 'data-role="content"' in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

To update below div :

```
    <div id="toadd" data-role="content">
        <p>Page 1 content</p>
                <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="g">
    <li><a href="bmw.html">BMW</a></li>
</ul>
    </div>
```

I'm using :

```
  $(document).ready(function() {                   
          $("#toadd ul").append("<li><a href=\"acura.html\">tes</a></li>");
       }   
    });
```

The problem is that the link is being add as a standard href :

[image]

How can I update the code so that 'test' uses the same jquery mobile styling as 'BMW' in attached image ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `$("#toadd ul").append("<li><a href=\"acura.html\">tes</a></li>").listview('refresh');`

[Check another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5925810/dynamically-adding-li-to-ul-in-jquery-mobile)

Comment: thanks, but should be .listview('refresh'); instead of ).listView('refresh');