# what is the "<li/>" tag for..?

Tags: jquery

What is the `<li/>` tag for..?

Can anyone point/find/share some documentation related to it..?

I found the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5926112/1864610) by "thecodeparadox"

I have tried hard to find some documentation related to that in vain..

Comment: I just find the related (possibly duplicate) question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867916/creating-a-div-element-in-jquery) which might help you a lot.

Answer (score 4):

jQuery provides an alternative to the traditional DOM createElement.

```
$("<li/>"); //create li element
```

If you wish to modify the element or bind events to it, you can do like below:

```
$("<li/>", { 
  click: function(){}, //allows you to bind events
  id: "test", // can be set html attribute
  addClass: "clickable" //allows you to bind jquery methods 
});
```

---

Documentation can be found [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/).

Comment: Adding on to this, in the example @Rony provides, a link `<a/>` is being appended to the list item (which itself has content added to it)

Comment: Are there any online docs that you can refer me to..? I am new to JQuery, and books on these topics tend to get outdated fast .. with newer, leaner and better ways to do the same thing...

Answer (score 3):

HTML provides tags for constructing ordered `<ol>` ("numbered") and unordered `<ul>` ("bulleted") lists.

Each item in such a list is indicated by the `<li>` tag.

```
<ul>
  <li>First!</li>
  <li>Second Base</li>
  <li>Three Strikes and you are Out</li>
</ul>
```

(sadly, often you will see the closing tag `</li>` omitted)
The notation `<TAG/>` is a shorthand for an empty tag (that is, equivalent to `<TAG></TAG>`).

There is little use for an empty list item, besides as a placeholder to be expanded upon later by javascript.

Answer (score 1):

The `<li/>` tag in jQuery is for tag creation, It's shorthand for `<li></li>`, in [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/):

> When the parameter has a single tag (with optional closing tag or quick-closing) — `$( "<img />" )` or `$( "<img>" )`, `$( "<a></a>" )` or `$( "<a>" )` — jQuery creates the element using the native JavaScript `.createElement()` function.

A basic sample:

```
$('<li/>').text('Hello World 1').appendTo('ul');
$('<li></li>').text('Hello World 2').appendTo('ul');
$('<li>').text('Hello World 3').appendTo('ul');
```

See this [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p5w89t3t/1/).